# Can I put a possessive pronoun between "as much...as"?

Tags: adverbs, conjunctions

I am wondering if it's published or fluent or common to apply a pronoun there?

For example:

> We want to make the blog as much **yours** as possible, but there are some guidelines...

Answer (score 3):

Definitely you can add the possessive pronoun! It is grammatical and defines the degree of possession in this particular case.

Please compare:

> The blog is as much yours as possible.
>
> The blog is as much yours as ours.